# Multiple ASP.NET User Controls on a page

Tags: asp.net

I'm adding 3-4 instances of a custom user control that I built in my ASP.NET project.

I have a couple of properties that I set in the aspx page at design time, but for some reason when I try to access the values in the user control, the only value that is available is the last instance of my user control that was added to the page.

It seems like the properties are public across all instances of a user control on a page.

Is anyone else seeing?  Do you know of a better way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where are you storing the result of setting a property? Can you post your properties get/set code? If you are just using Private variables of your control, they should be fine (presuming this isn't JS)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement [INamingContainer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help Anuraj, but public properties on the User Control are still being shared across all instances.